# React Nativ Swipe to delete Animation

Tags: react-native

i trying build a React native and Expo application with feature React Native Swipe to delete using Animation Reanimated 2, i'm follow some tutorial but i got some error and the Animation swip not working . i'm not sure how exactly animated a component on react native tell me please if what i write logically wrong

this is the error shown
[react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you're using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!

```
import Rect,{ useState }  from 'react';
import {View, Text,FlatList, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {PanGestureHandler, PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, { useAnimatedGestureHandler, useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated';


const RequestsBody =() => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([
       {name:'Ha', key:'1' , activities: '5', zone: 'out-of-zone Check-in'},
       {name:'Je', key:'2' , activities: '2', zone: 'out-of-zone Check-in'},
       {name:'Om', key:'3' , activities: '5', zone: 'out-of-zone Check-in'},  
   ])

    const translatX = useSharedValue(0)

      const panGesture = useAnimatedGestureHandler<PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent>({
          onActive: (event) => {
            translatX.value  = event.translationX
          },
          onEnd: () => {
              translatX.value = withTiming(0);
          },
      })

      const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(()=>({
          transform:[{
              translateX: translatX.value
          }]
      }))
 
  return (


      <View>
          <FlatList
             data={data}
             renderItem = {({item})=>(
                 <View style={{ width: 360, top:80}}>
                     <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={panGesture}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.container,rStyle]} >
                     <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold'}} >{item.name}</Text>
                     <Text style={{ position:"absolute",top:25 ,right:8,color:"#3781C4"}}>
                     {item.activities} activities</Text>  
                     <Text style={{ top:5 ,color:"#8D8D8D"}}>  {item.zone}</Text> 
                    </Animated.View>
                   </PanGestureHandler>
                 </View>    
                   )}
           />
       
      </View>
  )}



export default RequestsBody;
 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
          padding: 16,
          marginTop:4,
          backgroundColor: "#f5f3f3",
          borderRadius: 5,
          shadowColor: "#000",
          shadowOpacity: 0.06,
          shadowOffset: {
          width: 5,
          height: 5,
          },
        },
})
```

i think i have few SyntaxErrors but not sure how exactly i will correct them

Answer (score 0):

The version of the `react-native-gesture-handler` is not the latest one and this is incompatible with `react-native-reanimated`. Update the version of `react-native-gesture-handler` and additionally, I see that you are using `withTiming` function, it's not a valid function. It should be `withTiming(translatX, {duration: 200})` this way it will animate the value for 200ms.